# How do I enter an optimization problem?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to solve the following optimization problem:

```
min(x*y)
x => 500
y > 0
y / x >= 1/2
```

How do I enter this into *Mathematica*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Minimize[{x y, x >= 500 , y >= 0, y/x >= 1/2}, {x, y}]
```

In *Mathematica*:

(*

{125000, {x -> 500, y -> 250}}

*)